# Как использовать псевдоэлементы в FontAwesome 5?

Tags: html, css, css3, fontawesome

Помогите пожалуйста побороть псевдоэлементы в FA5

Сделал все по инструкции, но не работает!

Сайт собирается через gulp
Я использую FA5 Pro, JS версию:

```
'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/js/all.js',
```

Подтверждением тому что библиотека подключена и рабочая - другие иконки, которые отображаются через

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там где белый квадрат, там я пытаюсь использовать псевдоэлемент. Делаю все по инструкции:

**В JS файле:**

```
window.FontAwesomeConfig = {
    searchPseudoElements: true
}
```

**Верстка:**

```
<div class="icon SearchIcon"></div>
```

**Стили (SASS)**

```
.icon::before
    display: inline-block
    font-style: normal
    font-variant: normal
    text-rendering: auto
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased

.SearchIcon::before
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro"
    font-weight: 900
    content: "\f00d"
    width: 24px
    height: 24px
    font-size: 24px
    color: #fff
```

**Что не так то? :(**

Comment: Либо неправильно шрифт подключили, либо неправильный код символа. Еще у вас начертание bold, подозреваю что такого начертания в этом шрифте нет.

Comment: А конкретно эта нерабочая иконка через `<i>` отображается хоть? На первый взгляд вроде всё нормально

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev я поэкспериментировал с разными bold'ами — вроде бы работает

Comment: Через i все ок, я пробовал даже вставлять тупо код пример с их документации, всеравно квадрат. (https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements)

Comment: В веб-инспекторе проверяли, что эти стили не перебиваются какими-нибудь другими стилями в другом месте кода?